# How to get JPanels to vertically align?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

This is my first time really using graphics with Java.

I have a problem where I'm trying to populate a JScrollPane with an undefined number of panels (The following code is just a test; I know it's written using bad practices, but it's a test to see how to do it is all).

In the final program I'm going to have an ArrayList of orders (ArrayList size not predetermined), and in a JScrollPane I'm going to have a JPanel that holds a JPanel (each containing several labels) that will have details of each order.

here's the current test code (the JScrollPane is simply named scrollPane):

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    GroupLayout experimentLayout = new GroupLayout(panel);
    ArrayList<JPanel> panelArray = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i <3; i++){
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Hello");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Hi");
        panel2.add(label2);
        panel2.add(label3);
        //panel.add(panel2);
        panelArray.add(panel2);

    }

        experimentLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            experimentLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(panelArray.get(0))
                .addComponent(panelArray.get(1))
                .addComponent(panelArray.get(2))
           );

        experimentLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            experimentLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                                 //.addGroup(experimentLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(panelArray.get(0))
                .addComponent(panelArray.get(1))
                .addComponent(panelArray.get(2))
            );

        scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
```

When this runs, the JPanels that contain the labels are displayed horizontally (next to each other) instead of under one another.

Any help on how I could go about displaying them vertically would be a great help - Thank you all :)

Comment: Try a [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find GridLayout to be useful.